Simplify types in lean
With this definition:
def x : Fin (4 + 2) := Fin.mk 5 sorry

#check x

I'd like the type of x to be shown as Fin 6, but it shows as Fin (4 + 2) instead. How can this be done? I tried set_option pp.beta true, but it doesn't work.

I'm not sure why you want this, since you explicitly defined x to have type Fin (4 + 2), so why would you want Lean to tell you differently?
One thing you could do is the following:
#simp type_of% x -- Fin 6

Here type_of% e is a special elaborator that gives you the type of term e, and the #simp command simplifies a particular expression (in the same way that the simp tactic would).
